# Puppet Templates Iterations and yaml files

Tags: ruby, yaml, puppet, erb

I have the following yaml file in my data dir:

```
---
type:
  - config_setting1:
    foo: bar
  - config_setting2:
    foo: bar
```

My `.erb` template looks like this:

```
conf {
<% settings = YAML.load_file('/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/example/data/conf.yaml') -%>
<% settings['type'].each do |val| -%>
  <%= val %>
<% end -%>
}
```

When I run puppet on my agent machine I end up with this:

```
conf {
  {"config_setting1"=>nil, "foo"=>"bar"}
  {"config_setting2"=>nil, "foo"=>"bar"}
}
```

My end goal is to get the output to look like this:

```
conf {
  config_setting1 {
    foo: bar
  }
  config_setting2 {
    foo: bar
  }
}
```

I know I have some clean up to do on my template to actually get things to output that way, but I'm more focused on the how than the end result at the moment. As you can see I'm familiar with using the `['type']` on the end of the settings to navigate through the nested hash, and I realize I could create this structure pretty easily if I hard coded it but I want to understand how to use it iteratively. I've been attempting to follow the [Puppet Documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_iteration.html) on iterations but their examples don't work even when you copy them verbatim... which makes things a little difficult. How can I call pull out a single piece of data in a nested yaml file like I have? Either just the key or just a specific value? I tried something like:

```
<% settings['type'].each do |val| -%>
  <%= settings['val'] %>
<% end -%>
```

and multiple variations of this but I couldn't find the right syntax to get what I wanted. I've also tried having something along the lines of `<% settings['type'].each do |index, value| -%>` but I was unable to get any results I could use out of that either. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I'm open to being told that I'm going about this entirely the wrong way as well; if there is a better way to get at this data I'm all ears.

Another question that's less important, but still irks me - in my load_file I have the absolute path... is there a way to use relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazing how typing something out will answer your own question. I realized there was a pretty easy solution. If we take my template:

```
conf {
<% settings = YAML.load_file('/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/example/data/conf.yaml') -%>
<% settings['type'].each do |val| -%>
  <%= val %>
<% end -%>
}
```

and on line three replace `<% settings['type'].each do |val| -%>` with `<% settings.keys.each do |val| -%>` I'm able to get what I'm looking for. I'd still be interested if there is a better way to do this though, either how I'm loading via yaml or otherwise.

Comment: This does work, except that it misses the `{}` on your first keys in each element. Does that matter?

Comment: Conceptually it works, it just needed a little cleanup to get the actual end result.

Still trying to figure out the absolute path thing though!